# How to count all objects with specific key recursive?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

How i can count all objects that have specific key but if object can be nested and I do not know max depth of object because everytime is differente?

for exmaple once can be like this:

```
{
    "coins_series": [
        {
            "series": 1,
            "coins": [
                {
                    "_id": "65c8c78845d911984d98f6be",
                    "currency": "EUR",
                    "reverse_id": "SVN200701001REG",
                    "obverse_id": [
                        "EUR199901001FRO"
                    ],
                    "country": "SVN",
                    "commemorative": false,
                    "series": 1,
                    "min_year": 2007,
                    "denomination": 0.01,
                    "diameter": 16.25,
                    "thickness": 1.67,
                    "weight": 2.3
                },
                {
                    "_id": "65c8c78845d911984d98f6bf",
                    "currency": "EUR",
                    "reverse_id": "SVN200701002REG",
                    "obverse_id": [
                        "EUR199901002FRO"
                    ],
                    "country": "SVN",
                    "commemorative": false,
                    "series": 1,
                    "min_year": 2007,
                    "denomination": 0.02,
                    "diameter": 18.75,
                    "thickness": 1.67,
                    "weight": 3.06
                },
                {
                    "_id": "65c8c78845d911984d98f6c0",
                    "currency": "EUR",
                    "reverse_id": "SVN200701005REG",
                    "obverse_id": [
                        "EUR199901005FRO"
                    ],
                    "country": "SVN",
                    "commemorative": false,
                    "series": 1,
                    "min_year": 2007,
                    "denomination": 0.05,
                    "diameter": 21.25,
                    "thickness": 1.67,
                    "weight": 3.92
                },
                {
                    "_id": "65c8c78845d911984d98f6c1",
                    "currency": "EUR",
                    "reverse_id": "SVN200701010REG",
                    "obverse_id": [
                        "EUR200702010FRO"
                    ],
                    "country": "SVN",
                    "commemorative": false,
                    "series": 1,
                    "min_year": 2007,
                    "denomination": 0.1,
                    "diameter": 19.75,
                    "thickness": 1.93,
                    "weight": 4.1
                },
                {
                    "_id": "65c8c78845d911984d98f6c2",
                    "currency": "EUR",
                    "reverse_id": "SVN200701020REG",
                    "obverse_id": [
                        "EUR200702020FRO"
                    ],
                    "country": "SVN",
                    "commemorative": false,
                    "series": 1,
                    "min_year": 2007,
                    "denomination": 0.2,
                    "diameter": 22.25,
                    "thickness": 2.14,
                    "weight": 5.74
                },
                {
                    "_id": "65c8c78845d911984d98f6c3",
                    "currency": "EUR",
                    "reverse_id": "SVN200701050REG",
                    "obverse_id": [
                        "EUR200702050FRO"
                    ],
                    "country": "SVN",
                    "commemorative": false,
                    "series": 1,
                    "min_year": 2007,
                    "denomination": 0.5,
                    "diameter": 24.25,
                    "thickness": 2.38,
                    "weight": 7.8
                },
                {
                    "_id": "65c8c78845d911984d98f6c4",
                    "currency": "EUR",
                    "reverse_id": "SVN200701100REG",
                    "obverse_id": [
                        "EUR200702100FRO"
                    ],
                    "country": "SVN",
                    "commemorative": false,
                    "series": 1,
                    "min_year": 2007,
                    "denomination": 1,
                    "diameter": 23.25,
                    "thickness": 2.33,
                    "weight": 7.5
                },
                {
                    "_id": "65c8c78845d911984d98f6c5",
                    "currency": "EUR",
                    "reverse_id": "SVN200701200REG",
                    "obverse_id": [
                        "EUR200702200FRO"
                    ],
                    "country": "SVN",
                    "commemorative": false,
                    "series": 1,
                    "min_year": 2007,
                    "denomination": 2,
                    "diameter": 25.75,
                    "thickness": 2.2,
                    "weight": 8.5
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "country": "SVN"
}
```

and other time can be like this:

```
{
    "series": 2,
    "coins": [
        {
            "_id": "65c8c78845d911984d98f724",
            "currency": "EUR",
            "reverse_id": "VAT200502001REG",
            "obverse_id": [
                "EUR199901001FRO"
            ],
            "country": "VAT",
            "commemorative": false,
            "series": 2,
            "min_year": 2005,
            "max_year": 2005,
            "denomination": 0.01,
            "diameter": 16.25,
            "thickness": 1.67,
            "weight": 2.3
        },
        {
            "_id": "65c8c78845d911984d98f725",
            "currency": "EUR",
            "reverse_id": "VAT200502002REG",
            "obverse_id": [
                "EUR199901002FRO"
            ],
            "country": "VAT",
            "commemorative": false,
            "series": 2,
            "min_year": 2005,
            "max_year": 2005,
            "denomination": 0.02,
            "diameter": 18.75,
            "thickness": 1.67,
            "weight": 3.06
        },
        {
            "_id": "65c8c78845d911984d98f726",
            "currency": "EUR",
            "reverse_id": "VAT200502005REG",
            "obverse_id": [
                "EUR199901005FRO"
            ],
            "country": "VAT",
            "commemorative": false,
            "series": 2,
            "min_year": 2005,
            "max_year": 2005,
            "denomination": 0.05,
            "diameter": 21.25,
            "thickness": 1.67,
            "weight": 3.92
        },
        {
            "_id": "65c8c78845d911984d98f727",
            "currency": "EUR",
            "reverse_id": "VAT200502010REG",
            "obverse_id": [
                "EUR199901010FRO"
            ],
            "country": "VAT",
            "commemorative": false,
            "series": 2,
            "min_year": 2005,
            "max_year": 2005,
            "denomination": 0.1,
            "diameter": 19.75,
            "thickness": 1.93,
            "weight": 4.1
        },
        {
            "_id": "65c8c78845d911984d98f728",
            "currency": "EUR",
            "reverse_id": "VAT200502020REG",
            "obverse_id": [
                "EUR199901020FRO"
            ],
            "country": "VAT",
            "commemorative": false,
            "series": 2,
            "min_year": 2005,
            "max_year": 2005,
            "denomination": 0.2,
            "diameter": 22.25,
            "thickness": 2.14,
            "weight": 5.74
        },
        {
            "_id": "65c8c78845d911984d98f729",
            "currency": "EUR",
            "reverse_id": "VAT200502050REG",
            "obverse_id": [
                "EUR199901050FRO"
            ],
            "country": "VAT",
            "commemorative": false,
            "series": 2,
            "min_year": 2005,
            "max_year": 2005,
            "denomination": 0.5,
            "diameter": 24.25,
            "thickness": 2.38,
            "weight": 7.8
        },
        {
            "_id": "65c8c78845d911984d98f72a",
            "currency": "EUR",
            "reverse_id": "VAT200502100REG",
            "obverse_id": [
                "EUR199901100FRO"
            ],
            "country": "VAT",
            "commemorative": false,
            "series": 2,
            "min_year": 2005,
            "max_year": 2005,
            "denomination": 1,
            "diameter": 23.25,
            "thickness": 2.33,
            "weight": 7.5
        },
        {
            "_id": "65c8c78845d911984d98f72b",
            "currency": "EUR",
            "reverse_id": "VAT200502200REG",
            "obverse_id": [
                "EUR199901200FRO"
            ],
            "country": "VAT",
            "commemorative": false,
            "series": 2,
            "min_year": 2005,
            "max_year": 2005,
            "denomination": 2,
            "diameter": 25.75,
            "thickness": 2.2,
            "weight": 8.5
        }
    ]
}
```

some other time can be different format. I need to count all objects with commemorative key each time without specific data structure.

Comment: Isn't the second one just the value for the first one? So the structure is still the same? Also what have you tried so far and what do you mean by **count all objects**? Please provide some sample input and output.

Comment: Second one have one level less then first one. I need to go trough each level of nested objects and check if there is objects with `commemorative` key.  Also first one can have multiple `series` nested under `coins_series`  where each `series` will have object with that key nested. I am trying to count number of coins in data and `commemorative` is key that is common for each coin object. I know how to count them with `for` of `forEach` but only if i can predict how data structure will look. I want to write hook in react that will be used over multiple components with different data formats

Comment: I would suggest you don't write general purpose unknown data format handle everything functions, and instead have a series of easy clear specific use functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recursively iterate arrays and objects values and check that the objects contain your key:

```js
const countKey = (obj, key) => {
  let count = 0;
  if(Array.isArray(obj)){
    for(const item of obj){
      count += countKey(item, key);
    }
  } else if (obj && typeof obj === 'object'){
     for(const k in obj){
      if(k === key) count++;
      count += countKey(obj[k], key);
    }
  }
  return count;
};
    

// Example
const data = {"coins_series": [{"series": 1,"coins": [{"_id": "65c8c78845d911984d98f6be","currency": "EUR","reverse_id": "SVN200701001REG","obverse_id": ["EUR199901001FRO"],"country": "SVN","commemorative": false,"series": 1,"min_year": 2007,"denomination": 0.01,"diameter": 16.25,"thickness": 1.67,"weight": 2.3},{"_id": "65c8c78845d911984d98f6bf","currency": "EUR","reverse_id": "SVN200701002REG","obverse_id": ["EUR199901002FRO"],"country": "SVN","commemorative": false,"series": 1,"min_year": 2007,"denomination": 0.02,"diameter": 18.75,"thickness": 1.67,"weight": 3.06},{"_id": "65c8c78845d911984d98f6c0","currency": "EUR","reverse_id": "SVN200701005REG","obverse_id": ["EUR199901005FRO"],"country": "SVN","commemorative": false,"series": 1,"min_year": 2007,"denomination": 0.05,"diameter": 21.25,"thickness": 1.67,"weight": 3.92},{"_id": "65c8c78845d911984d98f6c1","currency": "EUR","reverse_id": "SVN200701010REG","obverse_id": ["EUR200702010FRO"],"country": "SVN","commemorative": false,"series": 1,"min_year": 2007,"denomination": 0.1,"diameter": 19.75,"thickness": 1.93,"weight": 4.1},{"_id": "65c8c78845d911984d98f6c2","currency": "EUR","reverse_id": "SVN200701020REG","obverse_id": ["EUR200702020FRO"],"country": "SVN","commemorative": false,"series": 1,"min_year": 2007,"denomination": 0.2,"diameter": 22.25,"thickness": 2.14,"weight": 5.74},{"_id": "65c8c78845d911984d98f6c3","currency": "EUR","reverse_id": "SVN200701050REG","obverse_id": ["EUR200702050FRO"],"country": "SVN","commemorative": false,"series": 1,"min_year": 2007,"denomination": 0.5,"diameter": 24.25,"thickness": 2.38,"weight": 7.8},{"_id": "65c8c78845d911984d98f6c4","currency": "EUR","reverse_id": "SVN200701100REG","obverse_id": ["EUR200702100FRO"],"country": "SVN","commemorative": false,"series": 1,"min_year": 2007,"denomination": 1,"diameter": 23.25,"thickness": 2.33,"weight": 7.5},{"_id": "65c8c78845d911984d98f6c5","currency": "EUR","reverse_id": "SVN200701200REG","obverse_id": ["EUR200702200FRO"],"country": "SVN","commemorative": false,"series": 1,"min_year": 2007,"denomination": 2,"diameter": 25.75,"thickness": 2.2,"weight": 8.5}]}],"country": "SVN"};
const count = countKey(data, "commemorative");
console.log(count); // 8
```

And benchmarking:

```
` Chrome/121
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>                     n=1       |      n=10       |     n=100      |     n=1000     
Alexander       1.00x   x1m 757 | 1.00x x100k 747 | 1.00x x10k 751 |  1.00x  x1k 736
trincot         3.00x x100k 227 | 2.93x  x10k 219 | 2.97x  x1k 223 |  2.99x x100 220
test30 (JSON)   8.40x x100k 636 | 8.09x  x10k 604 | 9.17x  x1k 689 | 10.98x x100 808
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```
` Firefox/122
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>                     n=1       |      n=10      |     n=100      |     n=1000    
Alexander       1.00x x100k 123 | 1.00x x10k  96 | 1.00x x10k 944 | 1.00x x100 101
trincot         4.07x x100k 501 | 5.47x x10k 525 | 5.74x  x1k 542 | 5.24x x100 529
test30 (JSON)   7.39x x100k 909 | 9.11x x10k 875 | 9.43x  x1k 890 | 9.13x x100 922
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
// Example
const $chunk = [{"coins_series": [{"series": 1,"coins": [{"_id": "65c8c78845d911984d98f6be","currency": "EUR","reverse_id": "SVN200701001REG","obverse_id": ["EUR199901001FRO"],"country": "SVN","commemorative": false,"series": 1,"min_year": 2007,"denomination": 0.01,"diameter": 16.25,"thickness": 1.67,"weight": 2.3},{"_id": "65c8c78845d911984d98f6bf","currency": "EUR","reverse_id": "SVN200701002REG","obverse_id": ["EUR199901002FRO"],"country": "SVN","commemorative": false,"series": 1,"min_year": 2007,"denomination": 0.02,"diameter": 18.75,"thickness": 1.67,"weight": 3.06},{"_id": "65c8c78845d911984d98f6c0","currency": "EUR","reverse_id": "SVN200701005REG","obverse_id": ["EUR199901005FRO"],"country": "SVN","commemorative": false,"series": 1,"min_year": 2007,"denomination": 0.05,"diameter": 21.25,"thickness": 1.67,"weight": 3.92},{"_id": "65c8c78845d911984d98f6c1","currency": "EUR","reverse_id": "SVN200701010REG","obverse_id": ["EUR200702010FRO"],"country": "SVN","commemorative": false,"series": 1,"min_year": 2007,"denomination": 0.1,"diameter": 19.75,"thickness": 1.93,"weight": 4.1},{"_id": "65c8c78845d911984d98f6c2","currency": "EUR","reverse_id": "SVN200701020REG","obverse_id": ["EUR200702020FRO"],"country": "SVN","commemorative": false,"series": 1,"min_year": 2007,"denomination": 0.2,"diameter": 22.25,"thickness": 2.14,"weight": 5.74},{"_id": "65c8c78845d911984d98f6c3","currency": "EUR","reverse_id": "SVN200701050REG","obverse_id": ["EUR200702050FRO"],"country": "SVN","commemorative": false,"series": 1,"min_year": 2007,"denomination": 0.5,"diameter": 24.25,"thickness": 2.38,"weight": 7.8},{"_id": "65c8c78845d911984d98f6c4","currency": "EUR","reverse_id": "SVN200701100REG","obverse_id": ["EUR200702100FRO"],"country": "SVN","commemorative": false,"series": 1,"min_year": 2007,"denomination": 1,"diameter": 23.25,"thickness": 2.33,"weight": 7.5},{"_id": "65c8c78845d911984d98f6c5","currency": "EUR","reverse_id": "SVN200701200REG","obverse_id": ["EUR200702200FRO"],"country": "SVN","commemorative": false,"series": 1,"min_year": 2007,"denomination": 2,"diameter": 25.75,"thickness": 2.2,"weight": 8.5}]}],"country": "SVN"}];

const $input = [];

// @benchmark test30 (JSON)
{
let count = 0

JSON.stringify($input, (key, value) => {
  if (key === 'commemorative') count++;
  return value;
})
count;
}

// @benchmark trincot
const countKey = (obj, key) =>
    Object(obj) !== obj ? 0  // A primitive value (base case)
       // A boolean indicating a match is coerced to 0 or 1:
    : (!Array.isArray(obj) && Object.hasOwn(obj, key)) +  
        // Recursive calls
        Object.values(obj).reduce((sum, obj) => sum + countKey(obj, key), 0);

countKey($input, "commemorative");

// @benchmark Alexander
{
const countKey = (obj, key) => {
  let count = 0;
  if(Array.isArray(obj)){
    for(const item of obj){
      count += countKey(item, key);
    }
  } else if (obj && typeof obj === 'object'){
     for(const k in obj){
      if(k === key) count++;
      count += countKey(obj[k], key);
    }
  }
  return count;
};
countKey($input, "commemorative");
}

/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this is several ways. Here is an approach using the `reduce` callback to make the recursive call and add up all the counts:

```js
const countKey = (obj, key) =>
    Object(obj) !== obj ? 0  // A primitive value (base case)
       // A boolean indicating a match is coerced to 0 or 1:
    : (!Array.isArray(obj) && Object.hasOwn(obj, key)) +  
        // Recursive calls
        Object.values(obj).reduce((sum, obj) => sum + countKey(obj, key), 0);

// Example
const data = {"coins_series": [{"series": 1,"coins": [{"_id": "65c8c78845d911984d98f6be","currency": "EUR","reverse_id": "SVN200701001REG","obverse_id": ["EUR199901001FRO"],"country": "SVN","commemorative": false,"series": 1,"min_year": 2007,"denomination": 0.01,"diameter": 16.25,"thickness": 1.67,"weight": 2.3},{"_id": "65c8c78845d911984d98f6bf","currency": "EUR","reverse_id": "SVN200701002REG","obverse_id": ["EUR199901002FRO"],"country": "SVN","commemorative": false,"series": 1,"min_year": 2007,"denomination": 0.02,"diameter": 18.75,"thickness": 1.67,"weight": 3.06},{"_id": "65c8c78845d911984d98f6c0","currency": "EUR","reverse_id": "SVN200701005REG","obverse_id": ["EUR199901005FRO"],"country": "SVN","commemorative": false,"series": 1,"min_year": 2007,"denomination": 0.05,"diameter": 21.25,"thickness": 1.67,"weight": 3.92},{"_id": "65c8c78845d911984d98f6c1","currency": "EUR","reverse_id": "SVN200701010REG","obverse_id": ["EUR200702010FRO"],"country": "SVN","commemorative": false,"series": 1,"min_year": 2007,"denomination": 0.1,"diameter": 19.75,"thickness": 1.93,"weight": 4.1},{"_id": "65c8c78845d911984d98f6c2","currency": "EUR","reverse_id": "SVN200701020REG","obverse_id": ["EUR200702020FRO"],"country": "SVN","commemorative": false,"series": 1,"min_year": 2007,"denomination": 0.2,"diameter": 22.25,"thickness": 2.14,"weight": 5.74},{"_id": "65c8c78845d911984d98f6c3","currency": "EUR","reverse_id": "SVN200701050REG","obverse_id": ["EUR200702050FRO"],"country": "SVN","commemorative": false,"series": 1,"min_year": 2007,"denomination": 0.5,"diameter": 24.25,"thickness": 2.38,"weight": 7.8},{"_id": "65c8c78845d911984d98f6c4","currency": "EUR","reverse_id": "SVN200701100REG","obverse_id": ["EUR200702100FRO"],"country": "SVN","commemorative": false,"series": 1,"min_year": 2007,"denomination": 1,"diameter": 23.25,"thickness": 2.33,"weight": 7.5},{"_id": "65c8c78845d911984d98f6c5","currency": "EUR","reverse_id": "SVN200701200REG","obverse_id": ["EUR200702200FRO"],"country": "SVN","commemorative": false,"series": 1,"min_year": 2007,"denomination": 2,"diameter": 25.75,"thickness": 2.2,"weight": 8.5}]}],"country": "SVN"};
const count = countKey(data, "commemorative");
console.log(count); // 8
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let totalCount=0;
const countFinder = (obj,key ='commemorative',val=undefined) =>{
  if(Array.isArray(obj)){
    for(let item of obj){
      countFinder(item,key,val);
    }
  }
  else if(typeof obj === 'object'){
    if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj,key)){
      if(val!==undefined){
        if(obj[key] === val){
          totalCount++;
          return;
        }
        return
      }
      else{
        totalCount++;
        return;
      }
    }
    else{
      for(let _key in obj){
        let item = obj[_key];
        countFinder(item,key,val);
      }
    }
  }
  else{
    return;
  }
  return totalCount
}
```

This function returns the count of the specified key within the given object or array. For example, when calling countFinder(obj, 'commemorative'), it will iterate through all elements in the first object to search for the 'commemorative' key. If called as countFinder(obj, 'commemorative', true), it will count the occurrences of the 'commemorative' key with a value of true. Don't forget to reset totalCount before calling the function.

Answer (score -1):

Consider using JSON.stringify for visiting all subobjects

(note that if you are serializing JSON which have `__proto__`, then it might be also counted, modify function with `hasOwnProperty` to handle this in your preffered way)

```
const exampleObject = {
  key1: 'value1',
  key2: 'value2',
  nested: {
    key1: 'nestedValue1',
    key3: 'nestedValue2',
  },
};

let count = 0

JSON.stringify(exampleObject, (key, value) => {
  if (key === 'key1') count++;
  return value;
})

console.log('count for key1', count)
```

Comment: waste of CPU & memory

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev benchmark/profiler please

Comment: already benchmarked, check my answer, your solution is the last

Comment: just found it, thanks a lot! So my answer is that if you need to get it done quickly, then 10x slower isn't that bad after all. Great benchmark by the way, I like the way it is inlined in the response. :) 

I might try reimplementing this in WASM so my solution wins the benchmark, we will see how it goes, when I will get it done it will ask you for benchmark update :-)

Comment: also one more thing @AlexanderNenashev, modern runtimes in the near future might be recognizing when the result of `JSON.stringify` is not used and could replace this with a regular visitor algorithms for all subobjects, then this source code would be the shortest implementation :)

Comment: interesting stuff, any updates are welcome :)